# Converting Joda DateTime to JavaTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, jodatime, java-time

I am trying to update my existing elasticsearch springboot project and as the source code is fairly old it still uses joda time. Now I have to upgrade all the functions of Joda time to java time. Now in the project We use Date Time of Joda Time

Code Sample for Joda Time

```
DateTime target = new DateTime(String targetDate, UTC);
```

We use this function currently in our code to convert a String to Date.
Using this function the String

`2022-10-01T00:00:00.000`

gets converted to

`2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z`

I am trying to replicate the same in java time.

I tried to parse the `targetDate` using `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` but both gave me errors.

> Text '2022-10-01T00:00:00.0000' could not be parsed at index 24

After some attempts I was able to move forward by using `LocalDateTime`

```
LocalDateTime target = LocalDateTime.parse(String targetDate);
```

Which was able to parse the String but the format was not correct the format I got was

`2022-10-01T00:00Z`

I also tried using the formatter with LocalDateTime

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSS'Z'");
LocalDateTime target= LocalDateTime.parse(targetDate,formatter);
```

But This Still gave me the Error

> Text '2022-10-01T00:00:00.0000' could not be parsed at index 24

Now I am a bit confused regarding this.

Any help is appreciated.
And Please correct me if my way of asking question or formatting is wrong at any point still new to this.

Regards.

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion but as pointed out I should have mentioned that I want the returned value as the *java.time datetime* object and not a *String* so that I can further perform some logic on it. Sorry for this.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you need a java.time *datetime object* that *represents* `2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z`? Or are you needing a *string* with this exact content? Please distinguish between the data itself and the format of the string representation of the data.

Comment: Yes, I need a java.time datetime object that represents the format not a String. Thanks for correcting me appreciate it.
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `String` `"2022-10-01T00:00:00.000"` can be parsed to a `LocalDateTime` because it only consists of year, month of year, day of month, hour of day, minute of hour, second of minute and fractions of second.

Your desired output `String` `"2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"` represents the same values plus an offset, the `Z` for *Zulu* time, which basically means UTC.

If you want to *add* an offset to the input `String` with `java.time`, you can parse it to a `LocalDateTime` and then append the desired offset, which results in an `OffsetDateTime`. You can print that in a desired format using a `DateTimeFormatter`, either use a prebuilt one or define one yourself.

Here's a small example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // input value
    String dateTime = "2022-10-01T00:00:00.000";
    // parse it and append an offset
    OffsetDateTime odt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // define a formatter that formats as desired
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    // and print the OffsetDateTime using that formatter
    System.out.println(odt.format(dtf));
}
```

Output:

```
2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

---

#### Clarification update:

There is just a single instance `OffsetDateTime` in my example with the following values:

- year (2022)
- month of year (10)
- day of month (1)
- hour of day (0)
- minute of hour (0)
- second of minute (0)
- franctions of second (0)
- offset (UTC / +00:00)

This instance of `OffsetDateTime` can be used for calculations (e.g. add/subtract days, months or other units) and it can be formatted as `String`. It also has a `toString()` method we don't have under control, but is used if you don't explicitly format it.

The following lines (first one is the last of my example above) show some different usages:

```
// print formatted by the DateTimeFormatter from the above example
System.out.println(odt.format(dtf));
// print the object directly, implicitly using its toString()
System.out.println(odt);
// print formatted by a prebuilt DateTimeFormatter (several are available)
System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
// print with a formatter that uses locale dependant expressions like month names
System.out.println(odt.format(
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMM dd HH:mm:ss xxx",
                                            Locale.ENGLISH)));
```

the last one also uses a different representation for UTC: instead of `Z` it shows the offset in hours and minutes.

Output:

```
2022-10-01T00:00:00.000Z
2022-10-01T00:00Z
2022-10-01T00:00:00Z
Saturday, Oct 01 00:00:00 +00:00
```

Comment: Thanks For the prompt response But this returned type is a String I want the returned value as an OffsetDateTime object to perform certain functions on it. I tried to parse this returned formatted string in OffsetDateTime.parse but it still returned `2022-10-01T00:00Z`. Is there any way I can get the returned value as an OffsetDateTime type and of the desired format.
Thanks & regards

Comment: @UmangPachaury So in short: You get a `String` without an offset and you want to transform it into an `OffsetDateTime` at UTC, is that correct?

Comment: Yes I suppose we can say that.

Comment: Well, that is already included in my answer, it is the line that starts with `OffsetDateTime odt = …`. The line parses the given `String` to a `LocalDateTime` and appends `ZoneOffset.UTC`. The output value is just one possibility of representing this `OffsetDateTime` as `String`, create by means of the formatter. You can perform actions on `odt`. If you just print the object `odt` (which isn't a `String`), it will implicitly use its `toString()` method and that `toString()` method creates a short output in this case, stripping off trailing zeros like seconds and smaller units.

Comment: Short: Parsing the result of my example is (1) redundant and (2) printing the `OffsetDateTime` without defining the output format prints the very same object in a different `String` representation. That's why I defined the `DateTimeFormatter` in my example.

Comment: @UmangPachaury - A date-time object is supposed to contain the information about date-time units and timezone-related information (if applicable e.g in the case of `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` etc.). It does not contain any information about the format. The output of `System.out.println(dtObj)` is the value of `dt.toString()` and for every date-time type, a default `toString` has been defined. For a custom string, you need to use a `DateTimeFormatter`. If you are still confused, print the value of `double d = 5.0000`. To get `5.0000` as the output, you need to use a `NumberFormat`.

Comment: *But this returned type is a String I want the returned value as an OffsetDateTime …* Just use the first two of the four code lines from `main` method from the answer and don’t use the last two lines.

Comment: Ok Thanks got it, I was getting confused because of this I actually didn't know that the toString() method was the one that was getting me confused. But Now I have this concept clear. Thanks everyone really appreciate it. Thanks @deHaar